# Finding GlassFish sub component versions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, jboss-weld

How do you (best) find the GlassFish sub component versions, e.g. for CDI (Weld)?

I know at webapp startup some versions are displayed, but I'm looking for a **reliable** listing like on page:

https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html

> This version has hundreds of bug fixes as well as updated versions for many of its sub-components:  Jersey 1.11, Grizzly 1.9.46, Weld 1.1.4.Final, EclipseLink 2.3.2,
>   Mojarra (JSF) 2.1.6, Metro 2.2, OSGi Core 4.3.0, JavaDB 10.8.1.2,
>   OpenMQ 4.5.2 and more.

...where this overview doesn't seem to be reliable at all, since I've just upgraded to 3.1.2.2 and my Weld version displayed is

> [org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap] (1) WELD-000900 1.1.8 (Final)

even though the release notes list Weld 1.1.4. (I've just asked the person responsible for our project setup: he has never upgraded the Weld version. We weren't even able to determine the location of the library itself in GF 3 :-) ... )

So, is there a reliable way to find sub component versions (also for sub components that don't log their version on startup)? As mentioned, I/we couldn't even find the respective JARs to look for ourselves...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish provides a command line tool "pkg". Set your directory to glassfish_home and type "pkg list" for a concise list and "pkg info" for more details.

If you use Maven you can also follow the dependancies and get more details from the repository. I am sure ant and other have similar options.

If you want to make changes for all apps then upgrade the server by: stop all domains, replace the jar files in %glassfish_home%\glassfish\modules. You might need to delete the OSGI cache in each domain by deleting sub folders. Restart the domains.

Finding the right files for each component is cumbersome but hopefully this points you in the right direction.